# Customized Home page for each user in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have an urgent requirement in which there should be Customized Home page for each user in SharePoint 2013.

In home page there will a web part zone with a drop down list with web part's name. If user select a web part name from drop down list then selected web part will be added into the web part zone.

Next time when he visit the page it should be in web part zone section of home page for that particular user only.

Comment: did you find a solution? Or do you have any news about what you tried?